# Javascript regex for formatting time

Tags: javascript, regex

Our organization's style guide specifies a date-time in this format: `Dec. 31 08:45 a.m.`. Our site runs Drupal, which is a PHP-based CMS. Its field formatting templates allow for date-formatting strings specified in the encoding which is defined in HPHP's `date()` function. It only offers `a`, which gives `pm`, and `A`, which gives me `PM`, but I don't see anything specifying one with periods.

Unfortunately, there is not an easy way to hook in to the platform to define a custom date format, so I figure the simplest way forward is to do a find-and-replace with javascript. What I want to do is replace instances in the format `NN:NN am` and `NN:NN pm` with `NN:NN a.m.`, etc.

Regexes have never been my strong suit. I can match date time format well enough( `[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] pm`), but I don't know how to perform the proper replacement.

How can I replace `am` and `pm` with properly abbreviated version, when they follow a four-digit time format?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post the code you've written already.

Comment: @MarcM. Hello, what I've tried so far is what I have already posted in the question: `[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] pm`. I don't know how to do the replace part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.replace(/(\d{2}:\d{2}\s?a|p)(m)/, '$1.$2');
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using the optional handler in the function `replace` to get the match string and replace the `am` or `pm` strings with `a.m` or `p.m` respectively.

```js
let str = "Dec. 31 08:45 am",
    result = str.replace(/([\d][\d]:[\d][\d] am|pm)/, function(match) {
      return match.replace('am', 'a.m.').replace('pm', 'p.m.');
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think one replacement using `str.replace(/([\d][\d]:[\d][\d]) ([ap])m/, "$1 $2.m.")` can work by grouping the A and P together.  I admit I haven't tested it extensively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex and replacement pattern to do, what you want:

Regex: `([0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\s)(a|p)(m)`

Replace: '$1$2.$3.'

How to use:

```
var text = 'Dec. 31 08:45 am';
text = text.replace(/([0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] )(a|p)(m)/, '$1$2.$3.');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'Dec. 31 08:45 AM, Jan. 1 10:15 pm'.replace(/(\d{2}:\d{2}) (a|p)(m)/ig, (match, p1, p2, p3) => {
  return `${p1} ${p2}.${p3}.`.toLowerCase();
});
```

yields the result

```
Dec. 31 08:45 a.m., Jan. 1 10:15 p.m.
```

Comment: The `i` after the regular expression is needed to ignore case if the input could also be uppercase like `AM`, and `PM`. The `g` is for replacing all occurrences. Otherwise only the first will be replaced. The solution uses some modern syntax that may not work in an older browser.